# Fill column with random numbers using datatool and PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, datatool, random-numbers, random

Consider the following `csv` file:

```
column1,column2
line1,
line2,
```

I want to fill `column2` with random numbers, preferably using PGF (simply because I already know a bit about PGF, but I am open to other solutions), and then print them.

Here is what I've tried (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv} %load db
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

%iterate a first time to fill column2
\DTLforeach{data}{%
    \columni=column1}{% 

    \DTLreplaceentryforrow{column2}{\pgfmathparse{random()}\pgfmathresult}

}

%iterate a second time to print the results
\DTLforeach{data}{%
    \columni=column1,
    \columnii=column2}{%

    \columni~ \columnii

}

\end{document}
```

...but I get the error `Undefined control sequence. }`.

Note that it works perfectly if I use `\DTLreplaceentryforrow{column2}{test}`.

The `datatool` user manual mentions: (emphasis added)

> `\DTLreplaceentryforrow{key}{value}`
>
> This replaces the entry for key with value. (**value is expanded.**)

I have a feeling that the problem lies in the expansion, but I am not quite sure, and I don't understand latex sufficiently to fix the issue.

(Additional question: do I really need to iterate twice? My tests tell me yes, but it strikes me as odd.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do this outside TeX? Do you need different values each time you compile? If not, this will be extremely inefficient. If so, it will be rather inefficient.

Comment: I think you may have to move `\pgfmathparse{random()}` before `\DTLreplaceentryforrow`. It's probably an expansion problem.